# stuck with picking up particular date in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I want to select a particular date from the calender so I wrote this code with the help of other sources:

```
WebDriverWait waitForDate = new WebDriverWait(driver,300);
        waitForDate.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='dpTradeDate']/span[@class='add-on']/i[@class='icon-calendar']")));



         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dpTradeDate']/span[@class='add-on']/i[@class='icon-calendar']")).click();


         //WebElement dateWidget=driver.findElement(By.className("datepicker-days"));

         //List<WebElement> rows=dateWidget.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
         List<WebElement> colmns=driver.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

         /*DatePicker is a table.So navigate to each cell   
           If a particular cell matches value 13 then select it  
          */  


         for (WebElement cell: colmns){  
              //Select 13th Date   
              if (cell.getText().equals("13")){  
              cell.findElement(By.linkText("13")).click();  
              }
         }
```

Each time I get an execution error message `timed out after 300 seconds` even though I put an explicit wait for 300 seconds. I guess this code is valid for picking up a particular date.

Answer (score 1):

If you're timing out, the WebdriverWait probably isn't finding anything - maybe a glitch in the XPath?

Try validating it manually on the page.
In the Chrome console, you can just use:

```
$x("xpath here")
```

Does that render any result?

(I would've commented rather than replied, but I'm short two reputation points.)

Answer (score 0):

> even though I put an explicit wait for 300 seconds

Your code does not wait for 300 seconds. Your code waits until the element located by the xpath statement "//div[@id='dpTradeDate']/span[@class='add-on']/i[@class='icon-calendar']" is visible. If it is not visible after 300 seconds, it throws the exact error you're seeing: `timed out after 300 seconds`. Therefore, your xpath is not pointing to a visible element.

Debug your xpath statement and your problem will be solved :)